# Locally compact Hausdorff space conditions

Tags: general-topology

Hi in the following theorem below I don't understand something in it. I don't understand how come where did they get $U \cup (Y - C) = Y - (C - U)$? In the proof below.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $C=Y-U$, we have

$$U\cup (Y-C)=U\cup (Y-(Y-U))=U\cup U=U=Y-(Y-U)=Y-((Y-U)-U)$$

$$=Y-(C-U).$$

By the way, you could state the theorem simply: A space is locally compact Hausdorff iff it has a one-point compactification, unique up to homeomorphism.

Comment: how do we know that C = Y - U ?

Comment: that's the definition! See third paragraph of proof.

Comment: oh I see since any compact subspace of haussdorff space is closed so it must be of the form Y - U. Alright I see

Comment: no, $U$ is a given open set. So $Y-U$ is closed, therefore compact.

Comment: I still don't understand. why do we know that C = Y - U for that particular U in the proof could you add more details above in your answer ?

Comment: $C$ is defined to be $Y-U$! I'll add some more details.

Comment: good I understand now